# Click ExoPlayer notification to open app

Tags: exoplayer

Using ExoPlayer and PlayerNotificationManager to show media playback progress in notification, now how can I open app by clicking on notification?

Answer (score 6):

You directly override this method under MediaDescriptor when you try to createNotificationChannel through PlayerNotificationManager

```
@Override

 public PendingIntent createCurrentContentIntent(Player player){
     Intent intent = new Intent(YourService.this,YourMediaActivity.class);
                       PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity
                                (YourService.this, 0, intent, 0);
                        return contentPendingIntent;
                    }
```